# How to rebind names in outer function?

Tags: python

```
>>> def QQ():
...     a = 0
...     def QQQ():
...         global a
...         a += 1
...     QQQ()
...
>>> QQ()
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

It appears that `global` doesn't work in this scenario. What else can I do, other than the 1-element list trick?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What should I call it? Rebinding?

Comment: That's exactly correct.

Comment: @chenaren: Yes. In Python, mutating is something you do to values; rebinding is something you do to names. (Python doesn't have "variables" in the sense that C++ or Java does, so you can't speak of "mutable variables". `+=` mutates the value if possible, creates a new value if not, then rebinds the name either way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.x, you can use [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

```
>>> def QQ():
...     a = 0
...     def QQQ():
...         nonlocal a
...         a += 1
...     QQQ()
...     return a
...
>>> QQ()
1
```

If you're using Python 2.x, you can't do it. That's why `nonlocal` was added. So, you have to use some kind of mutable wrapper, like the 1-element list trick.*

[PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) explains all of the gory details (including why Python doesn't do "classic static nested scoping" by default, and requires you to be explicit about it).

---

* Or upgrade to 3.x, of course. Whenever you find yourself asking how to bind to nonlocals, delegate to another generator, get fully-qualified class names, specify keyword-only parameters, unpack a variable-length iterator but capture the last value separately, or anything else that's trivial in 3.x but painful in 2.x, it's worth re-asking yourself whether it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an arbitrary list you could use the built in `*args` and `**kwargs` something like

```
def f(**kwargs):
    kwargs['start'] = kwargs.get('start', 0)
    def g():
        kwargs['start'] += 1
        return kwargs['start']
    return g
```

it's essentially the same "hack", this is just less ugly imo.

Comment: I personally find this less ugly as well, but the "list hack" is more well-known, and enshrined in official documentation (the Programming FAQ, PEP 3104, example code in/linked from the stdlib docs, etc.), so I generally do it the ugly way. (If it helps, tell yourself that what you're doing is a hacky workaround, and therefore it's _good_ that it's uglier and more visible…) At any rate, the only _clean_ solutions are (a) use an object instead of a closure when you need to rebind values, (b) use a dict instead of separate variables in the outer scope, or (c) upgrade to Python 3.x.